# ISNULL() returning NULL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, isnull

Why does the following simple query return null when there are no matching rows (`<Condition>` is not met by any row)?

```
SELECT ISNULL(MyField, 0) FROM [MyTable] WHERE <Condition>
```

I have tried `COALESCE()` as well, with similar results. How can I return zero when there are no matching rows?

Comment: if `<Condition>` is not met, then there will be no row. Using `count(*)` will return number of matching rows, if no row then it show `0`.

Comment: @Bharadwaj: I know that and that's why I posted the question. How can I return zero in that case?

Comment: Use `IF @@ROWCOUNT > 0 ...` See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187316.aspx

Comment: `SELECT count(*) FROM [MyTable] WHERE <Condition>` will give `0` if no row matching

Comment: Just check if the query returned a row in your program logic

Comment: Thanks. I can think of other workarounds that take multiple statements. I was looking for some in-line/built-in function that would handle the situation. I was initially of the view that `ISNULL()` already handles the situation, but now it looks like that is not a possibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work, provided you expect `condition` to reduce the result set to either 0 or 1 row:

```
SELECT ISNULL((SELECT MyField FROM [MyTable] WHERE <Condition>),0)
```

That is, create an outer query with no `FROM` clause (which will therefore always generate exactly one row) and then use a subquery to obtain your 0 or 1 row of actual data.

Comment: Brilliant. It's one-liner and a simple solution of a simple problem. I do however wonder why `ISNULL` behaves differently when applied on a subquery vs. when applied on a field, even when the number of returned rows is zero in both cases.

Comment: @dotNET - as I say, my *outer* query has one row, not zero. The `SELECT` clause is a description of what to do for *each* row in its result set. If its got zero rows to deal with, it will do its work zero times.

Comment: Oops. I see that now. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
SELECT ISNULL(COUNT(MyField), 0) FROM [MyTable] WHERE <Condition>
```

It'll return `0` if row is missing.

Comment: But it will return count if condition is met. :)

Comment: `COUNT` always gives a number, never be `null`, afaik

Comment: @Bharadwaj: You didn't get the point. I'm saying that it will not return `MyField` when the condition is met. So this solution is not doing exactly what the query in question needs to do.

Comment: @DotNET I got your point, I am thinking on it. As far my thinking, you may need to use `Exist()` with `if-else` block

Answer (score 0):

You cannot convert `0 rows` to `1 row with a null value` with any sql built-in fuction because that may cause mis-interpretation of data

But you can customize your result using the below logic (same as you do in .net).

```
If (select COUNT(MyField) FROM [MyTable] WHERE <Condition>)=0
select 0 as [MyField]
else
SELECT ISNULL(MyField, 0) as [MyField] FROM [MyTable] WHERE <Condition>
```